# Window api size and move a console

Tags: c++, api, console, window

I'm trying to make a function a function who allow me to move & resize the console on windows.
Currently I did that :

```
int CMD::setSizeAndMove(int top, int left, int width, int height)
//Here we change the size of the window, if the buffer is ok, and change the position
{
    SMALL_RECT rect;
        rect.Top = top;
        rect.Left = left;
        rect.Bottom = height;
        rect.Right = width;
    return SetConsoleWindowInfo(m_consoleHandle, true, &rect);
}
```

The buffer is ok. I tried to look error and I get one. The error n°87 : Invalid Parameter : The parameter is incorrect.

How to solve this problem, I don't really undertsand what I do false.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug in your code:

```
SMALL_RECT rect;
    rect.Top = top;
    rect.Left = left;
    rect.Bottom = height;
    rect.Right = width;
```

The meaning of `height` is not the same as `bottom`. Similarly for `width` and `right`. Try changing to something like:

```
 SMALL_RECT rect;
    rect.Top = top;
    rect.Left = left;
    rect.Bottom = height + top;
    rect.Right = width + left;
```